# Spring configure application.properties for placeholder in multitenant environment

Tags: java, spring, placeholder, application.properties

I have a multi tenant environment so I need to change some path from application.properties in runtime to use the folder of specific tenant.
For example in my application properties:

```
image.avatars=C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/${tenant}/Avatars/
```

in my class I use

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;
private static final String DIRECTORY_USER_IMAGE = "image.avatars";
.....Method
    env.getRequiredProperty(DIRECTORY_USER_IMAGE)
```

I read about `env.resolveRequiredPlaceholders` but I don't understand how it can be used in my case since it has only one parameter like so `env.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(TenantContext.getCurrentTenant())`.
Is there a simple way to change the placeholder without manipulate String(with replace)?
I thought that env.resolveRequiredPlaceholders required the name of properties and the varargs of placeholder but it is different.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.format()`.

Just use `%s` in properties

```
image.avatars=C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/%s/Avatars/
```

And the in the code

```
String.format(imageavatars, tenant)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be not exactly what you want (because I struggle to understand your scenario), but what about putting

```
image.avatars=C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/${tenant}/Avatars/
```

in your `application.properties`, and using

```
@Value("${image.avatars}")
private String DIRECTORY_USER_IMAGE;
```

in your bean/service and running the app with a command line argument like

```
--tenant="FooBar"
```

This would give `DIRECTORY_USER_IMAGE` the value `C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/FooBar/Avatars/` and you could change the CLI argument according to your needs. But be aware that `DIRECTORY_USER_IMAGE` is not `static final` anymore.

I hope I got your requirements right.